# clipboard extension chrome without input display

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I need copy custom text to clipboard for example after click button then copy to clipboard '1234'
it's work with `onClick` but I write with id not working`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var link = document.getElementById('copyToClipboard');

 link.addEventListener('click', 
  function copyToClipboard(text) {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
   input.style.position = 'fixed';
   input.style.opacity = 0;
   input.value = text;
   document.body.appendChild(input);
   input.select();
   document.execCommand('Copy');
   document.body.removeChild(input);
  }
 );
});
```

```html
<button id="copyToClipboard('1234')">Copy text</button>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I"m thinking of this solution since you already defined a function on your button.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var link = document.getElementById('1234');

    link.addEventListener('click', 
        function copyToClipboard() {

        const input = document.createElement('input');
            input.style.position = 'fixed';
            input.style.opacity = 0;
            input.value = this.id;
            document.body.appendChild(input);
            input.select();
            document.execCommand('Copy');
            document.body.removeChild(input);
        }
    );
});
</script>
<button id="1234" >Copy text</button>
```